# Insert datetime from asp.net to sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a problem. I need insert `DateTime` into SQL from ASP.NET. I have a calendar for inserting date and two `DropDownlist`. One for hours and other for minutes. I don't know how insert date from calendar and time (hours and minutes) all at once. This code insert only date. For example `28.3.2013 0:00:00`.

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Milniky ( datetime ) values ('" + CalendarDz.SelectedDate + DropDownListHz + DropDownListMz +"')";
```

Comment: Did you debug 101 and print out the command to see what it is trying to send to SQL Server? Could you show us?

Comment: Glazing over the fact that SQL queries shouldn't be built by string concatenation like this... What is the actual string value of the query after you built it?  We can't see the runtime values for things like `DropDownListMz` from here.

Comment: In general it's also not a good idea to use potential reserved keywords as column names in your database.  You can explicitly define it as an object name by wrapping it in square brackets (`[datetime]`), but it's still good to avoid using that name anyway.  After all, the name doesn't even convey what it represents, only the data type it holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider creating a `DateTime` object and parameters while inserting to prevent bad data.

```
int hour = int.Parse(DropDownListHz.SelectedValue);
int minute = int.Parse(DropDownListMz.SelectedValue);
DateTime dt = CalendarDz.SelectedDate;
dt.AddHours(hour);
dt.AddMinutes(minutes);
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Milniky ( datetime ) values (@dt)";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dt", dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
```

You may also want to use `DateTime.TryParse(s)` to give a better user experience

However in your specific command, I suspect you need to add a space and a colon to the statement to concatenate a date.

Currently your command looks like it's creating something like `2013-3-28130` and what you want is something like `2013-3-28 1:30`.

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Milniky ( datetime ) values ('" + CalendarDz.SelectedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " " + DropDownListHz + ":" + DropDownListMz +"')";
```

Comment: Debug write s "1. 3. 2013 0:00:00 18:20" string

Comment: Change `CalendarDz.SelectedDate` to `CalendarDz.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I don´t know what is this, but when I insert ("yyyy-MM-dd") and i select day bigger that 12 i have a message "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated." But if I change mounth for day ("yyyy-dd-MM") and select day bigger that 12 message is "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime type."

Comment: Change it to `MM/dd/yyyy` and give it a try

Comment: Didn´t work "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime type."

Comment: Please post the string it's attempting to convert, something else is wrong

Comment: string s = CalendarDz.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " " + DropDownListHz.SelectedValue + ":" + DropDownListMz.SelectedValue;

Comment: Change `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` to `.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime type

Comment: And the exception is here DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(s);

Comment: I've changed the answer to try to work around that since it's difficult to see what is going on in your code.

Comment: It is the same, if I select day bigger that 12, there is out-of-range exception.

Comment: I've changed the parameter and the answer. Change `dt.ToString()` to `dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`. If this doesn't work, will you please paste the final query that gets executed? There is something wrong with the query itself if it is happening there